# Rails' stale? method for sitemap always returns HTTP 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, etag

My Ruby on Rails application uses the following controller code to generate a sitemap.xml file:

```
class SitemapController < ApplicationController
  layout nil

  def index
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
    last_post = Post.last
    if stale?(:etag => last_post, :last_modified => last_post.updated_at.utc)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { @posts = Post.sitemap } # sitemap is a named scope
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My understanding is that the `stale?` method should ensure a HTTP 304 Not Modified response if the content hasn't changed. However, whenever I test this using curl or a web browser I always get an HTTP 200:

```
$ curl --head localhost:3000/sitemap.xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2009 15:50:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Apr 2009 16:52:07 GMT
X-Runtime: 100
ETag: "5ff2ed60ddcdecf291e7191e1ad540f6"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 29318
```

Am I using the `stale?` method correctly? Is it even possible to test this locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is likely that your Rails code is just fine but curl is not sending the If-Modified-Since header when you perform your test.  From the [curl docs](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/index.html):

> TIME CONDITIONS
>
> HTTP allows a client to specify a time
>   condition for the document it
>   requests. It is If-Modified-Since or
>   If-Unmodified-Since. Curl allow you to
>   specify them with the -z/--time-cond
>   flag.
>
> For example, you can easily make a
>   download that only gets performed if
>   the remote file is newer than a local
>   copy. It would be made like:
>
> curl -z local.html
>   http://remote.server.com/remote.html
>
> Or you can download a file only if the
>   local file is newer than the remote
>   one. Do this by prepending the date
>   string with a '-', as in:
>
> curl -z -local.html
>   http://remote.server.com/remote.html
>
> You can specify a "free text" date as
>   condition. Tell curl to only download
>   the file if it was updated since
>   yesterday:
>
> curl -z yesterday
>   http://remote.server.com/remote.html
>
> Curl will then accept a wide range of
>   date formats. You always make the date
>   check the other way around by
>   prepending it with a dash '-'.

Comment: That's great, I was hoping it would be helpful to you.  Thanks for the update!